# Stretch image height css

Tags: html, css, image, resize, height

I'm trying to get two images to fill a cell. Both are set to widths of 100% and the horizontal stretch is perfect. Both are set to heights of 50%, one is perfect, the other overlaps the cell and spills into the cell below it because it doesn't stretch to the height I specified but a proportional height based off the width.

http://shears-001-site1.mywindowshosting.com/bet.aspx

If you see, the bottom image is spilling over to the cell below it. I want it to fit nicely in the cell it is in and I don't care if it looks funny.

EDIT: It seems like the issue is with using percent heights for the divs. If em or pixels are used it scales correctly, but percent and it just goes crazy.

Comment: Can you share some code? Or in jsfiddle? I am thinking that your images height and width are not relative to cell size. Thanks.

Comment: <td style='padding-top: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%; width: 25%; vertical-align: top;'>
<img src='logo.jpg' style='border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: #E70303; margin-top: 0%; padding-top: 0%; margin-bottom: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%; width: 100%; height: 50%; display: inline-block;' alt='VGBC Logo' title='VGBC Logo'>
<br>
<img src='PM.jpg' style='margin-top: 0%; padding-top: 0%; margin-bottom: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%; width: 100%; height: 50%; display: inline-block;' alt='PM Logo' title='PM Logo'>
</td>

Comment: please add clear and float as left on img and avoid <br/> in between both <img>

Comment: I did that and its still the same as it was before. They are both 100% of the cell width, but only one is 50% of the cell height.

Comment: and avoid height on top <img>

Comment: removing height on top img allowed the bottom img to not spill over the cell, however now the cell is stretched longer than the height specified. Also, why does removing the height of the top img make them both fit in? 50+50=100 so shouldn't it not matter?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top;">
  <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</td>
```

or in **css**

```
img
{
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Still have problem with the cell now being longer than specified. I don't want the cell to stretch/compress, just the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzudK/2/)

```
td{
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.test{
   border-bottom-style: solid; 
   background-color: yellow; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 50%;    
   position: relative;
}

img{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;     
}
```

Comment: Tried this and its the same issue as the other suggestions. The cell gets stretched to a size to fit both images at their proportional heights instead of staying at the specified height and shrinking the images.

Answer (score 0):

i think ur both images are differ in hight thts y u r getting the problem ...try to make both image same height and the share 50 % both ...

Comment: Whats the point of the height attribute then if I have to go out of my way making sure each image is the exact same pixel size on the file system?

Comment: if u dnt want to go out then apply height in pixel in html...i think percentage contains some kind issue with images in ur case....u have two option apply height in pixel either change size of image in file